# Pandas spline interpolation wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation

Pandas (Version 1.3.5) and SciPy (Version 1.7.3) give different result for spline interpolation and from my understanding pandas is wrong:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'values': [10, 12, 15, None, None, None, None, 10, 5, 1, None, 0, 1, 3],})
df['interpolated_pandas'] = df['values'].interpolate(method='spline', axis=0, order=3)
df[['interpolated_pandas', 'values']].plot.line();
```

gives me:
[image]

And

```
idx = ~df['values'].isna()
f = interpolate.interp1d(df[idx].index, df.loc[idx,'values'], kind=3) # kind: an integer specifying the order of the spline interpolator to use
df['interpolated_scipy'] = f(df.index)
df[['interpolated_scipy', 'values']].plot.line();
```

gives me:
[image]

Is there something wrong in my code or is my understanding wrong? Or is this an actual bug in Pandas?

Comment: Not sure, but did you try `interpolate.CubicSpline` instead of `interpolate.interp1d` if theyre giving same result?

Comment: I just tried `CubicSpline` but it gives exact same results as `interp1d`. At least SciPy seems consistent here...

Comment: But thanks for the pointer. I just found that pandas uses `UnivariateSpline` and not `interp1d`, which gives different results due to a smoothing factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas uses `UnivariateSpline` which by default uses a "smoothing factor used to choose the number of knots", see [pandas code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f00ed8f47020034e752baf0250483053340971b0/pandas/core/missing.py#L502) and [scipy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline).
To achieve same results, we need add `s=0` in the function call:

```
df['interpolated_pandas'] = df['values'].interpolate(method='spline', axis=0, order=3) # default with smoothing factor
df['interpolated_pandas_s0'] = df['values'].interpolate(method='spline', axis=0, order=3, s=0) # without smoothing factor and same as `interp1d`
```